# Wikipedia categories for articles by id

Tags: java, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I would like to get a list of categories of Wikipedia articles. I currently use this api

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&pageids=17566205|39952380&inprop=url&format=xml
```

However, I need the categories for over 4M articles and wonder if there are data dumps around for such task. I don't need the textual content of a page, only its categories.

Thank you.

Comment: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html Please choose language and then find categories dump.

Comment: What is useful (for a computer scientist) can't be off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MediaWiki database schema, there is the [`categorylinks`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Categorylinks_table) table, which contains (amongst others) the fields `cl_from` (ID of the page) and `cl_to` (name of the category):

```
+-------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field             | Type                         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| cl_from           | int(10) unsigned             | NO   | PRI | 0                 |                             |
| cl_to             | varbinary(255)               | NO   | PRI |                   |                             |
| cl_sortkey        | varbinary(230)               | NO   |     |                   |                             |
| cl_sortkey_prefix | varbinary(255)               | NO   |     |                   |                             |
| cl_timestamp      | timestamp                    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| cl_collation      | varbinary(32)                | NO   | MUL |                   |                             |
| cl_type           | enum('page','subcat','file') | NO   |     | page              |                             |
+-------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

The data of this table is available from the [WikiMedia dumps](http://dumps.wikimedia.org) page as SQL dump (e.g. `enwiki-20140903-categorylinks.sql.gz`).

Comment: Thank you, is there a text-like dump or only sql

Comment: Only SQL. So the most convenient way, if you need a different format, would be to import it into some DB first. I once created a parser which would read directly from MediaWiki's SQL dumps and convert it to my needs, but that's PITA and I would definitely not recommend it.